# Priority executing WHERE clause in JOIN keyword

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know, When I use `where` clause following the directives `join`, What happen ?

In fact, something that I want to know is priority of execute. For instance, Consider the below code:

```
select * from tablename1 t1 inner join tablename2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id where id='10'
```

Then what happen in the above code first?

SQL will select all rows that their `id` are 10 and then runs `join` keyword ?
Or `join` keyword runs in first and then `where` clause?

Comment: Maybe, maybe, maybe.  SQL statements describe the result set.  They do not specify the specific order of processing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is it possible to I define so that `where` runs first ?

Comment: I have no idea what that means in the context of a SQL statement.  Why would you even care?  In general, you should care about the result set and the performance of the query, not the mechanics of the execution engine.

Comment: @MauricioTrajano . . . I hope this is not a duplicate of that question, because the top answer is incorrect.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Why would you even care? It is important to me, Because, If `where` runs, my results are almost 10 rows, then `Join` will apply on 10 rows. but if `join` runs first, my results are almost 100 rows and then `where` will apple. I think the fist case is more optimized. `where` is more faster than `join` reasonably.

Comment: @stack . . . Trust the database to do the right thing.  Verify that it does, then tweak the query and the data structure if you need to.  The execution plan is the job of the optimizer, so you can focus on what you want to do, not on how the database does it.  Besides, for 10x10 rows, either method should be so fast you won't really notice the difference.

Comment: [I think this may help the future users](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5038/sql-server-join-where-processing-order/5040#5040)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question **Join** runs first, but if you want to filter try this query

```
select * 
from (
  select *
  from tablename1
  where id='10') t1,
  (
  select *
  from tablename2 
  where id = '10'
) t2
```

**Update:**
As others suggest checking execution plan will help to understand how query performs, but still if you want to decide on your own, better to do it yourself.

**Update 2:**
Thanks to @GiorgiNakeuri for his points. As mentioned in the comments after a change to inner queries **Inner Join** is not needed. A simple cartesian join is enough.

Read [Art of SQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008945) for more info on sql optimisations.

For more advanced knowledge try [SQL Tuning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005733)

Comment: Putting that select in parenthases doesn't guarantee that it whould first do that select. How do you think if subquery will return million of rows where id = 10 but there is no rows in table2 it will still read those million rows?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Right, made an update on the query. Original query was incorrect in the answer. Should've t1.id = '10

Comment: My answer was pointing on the fact, that a where condition can be put as a nested query, but agree on your point if both of the table have the same id column, filter should be applied for both of the queries

Comment: And still putting both in subquery will not guarantie that. Engine still may decide first join and then apply where clauses.

Comment: Note that the actual physical execution of the statement is determined by the query processor and the order may vary from this list...https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx    you can find similar for other engine.

Comment: Not sure about how optimisation may apply on the query, which depends on the version of the db, but a nested where condition is actually a way to point a where condition as a priority for executing. Any other way to achive that?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Thanks for the link, but that's for SQL Server and not MySQL. Is the logic of engine the same for them?

Comment: I don't know what is there inside but they are construcy the way you tell them what you want and you don't care how it does it. Can you check the plan with your query bu change `on t1.id=t2.id` with `on 0 = 1`. I am pretty sure you will see 0 = 1 first in query plan. It is logical because if both subselects return millions of rows, the outer join will filter them out by always false predicate. I don't think it will read 1000000 rows first just to filter them out.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Indeed. Join is not needed, simple cartesian join is enough. Check "Art of sql" book, if you want more info on query optimisations

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer your question  yourself you can use `EXPLAIN`

Run

`EXPLAIN select * from tablename1 t1 inner join tablename2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id where id='10'`

`EXPLAIN` is pretty cool. I use it almost every day. It helps me to understand complex queries.

And it will also suggest you which columns you should index and how to improve your original query